# Finding which user was removed

Tags: discussion

I just lost 55 reputation because a user was removed. I know that there is not much that I can do about this, but is there anyway that I could see which user was removed or at least from what posts my reputation loss came from?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1352/2451

Answer (score 4):

[This Mother Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140063/user-was-removed-need-to-show-which-answer-question-loses-its-reputation) (*User was removed need to show which answer/question loses its reputation*) seems to be relevant with the answer including

> As Flexo pointed out in comments, this would also undermine the anonymity of voting. I don't see that sufficient advantage is gained by showing this information to offset this problem.

If you are interested in the posts you lost the rep on, the Android App (as of the latest version) shows, on the rep notification, the posts that were upvoted by the removed user (so `-10 <post name>` appears). There was a Mother Meta post on this, but I can't find it at the moment; I'm also unsure if this is possible on the Apple App.

Comment: Also, it was recently said in chat (check transcript on June 12) that there were going to be multiple accounts deleted. IDK if your rep loss is associated with that, but if it is then that'd be several accounts' voting privacy lost.

Comment: FYI, Kyle Kanos is referring to e.g. [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22167647#22167647) chat message of mine.

Comment: As a quick check, if the lost reputation points happened on Jun 12th, 2015, at 14:58-15:00 or 23:06-23:07 o'clock, then it is almost certainly connected with the removal of several sockpuppet accounts.

Comment: @Qmechanic So you're saying the 80 rep I lost there is because somebody liked my posts so much that they registered a sockpuppet to upvote them twice? I think I'm OK with that, then.

Comment: @Qmechanic I am pretty sure I know at least one user account that disappeared around that time - actually a remarkably active one that had recently showed up. I suppose it would be bad form to state the name here although it probably was one of the SP accounts?

Comment: @Floris: Yeah, you are right. No need to talk about the dead. Unless of course they don't stay dead. Then you are welcome to flag.